# how to do xor operation for a set of binary numbers in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I would like to know how I can use 131 bit to be XOR individually bit by bit. What is happening now the whole string will be considered as one input. While, I want the xor being done for bit by bit .

```
S1 = 676321722223643644634325325642527565610; 
binaryS1=dec2bin(S1);

S2 = 211532172222364365657474773828899156560; 
binaryS2=dec2bin(S2);


f1 = xor(binaryS1, binaryS2);
```

Comment: [`bitxor`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitxor.html) is your friend.

Comment: @Hoki why not post as answer?

Comment: note: in Matlab you cannot expect 131 bit operations in one shot, you'll have to split your bits into smaller packets. Matlab longest unsigned integer format `uint64` is only 64 bits wide. But the default casting is to `double` type (eg: 64 bit float) So when you do `S1=676321722223643644634325325642527565610;`, you cast your number into double and you messed up all your bits. You have to present your data in smaller packets.

Comment: @Shai, it's not that simple, the input he presented do not work for a simple example of `bitxor` (can only handle 64 bits at a time). I don't know what type are his input numbers (unsigned/signed ... 131 bit unsigned integer would be a first guess but it's very odd as an integer type).

Comment: Your lines `S1 = 676321722223643644634325325642527565610; S2 = 211532172222364365657474773828899156560;` cannot define those numbers exactly `double` data type only has about 15 significant digits. Even if you use `uint64`, it's still not enough

Comment: @Hoki thanks for your response ,  i am working on simulation that needs long integers , how i can divide the integer number into two or three parts of 64 bits , then xor the values and recombine them again in the same order. thanks mate

Comment: @LuisMendo thanks mate , i have explained the same to Hoki..

Comment: What platform/system are you working which handle 131+ bits data types in the first place ? The splitting into 64 bits chunks (or smaller) should be done on the system which can handle these numbers (or which generated them in the first place). On any other system, you'd have to write your own data type class if you want to handle that ... not a quick and easy task.

Comment: What is the class of `S1`?